# C++ output shown in debug console on Visual Studio Code on macOS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have written some C++ code on Visual Studio Code on macOS with only the clang compiler and C/C++ extension without Code Runner, while I can only get the output from the debug console as shown below.
[image]

I have ever written the same code on windows11 with Visual Studio Code, I remember I can get the output from the terminal. My question is how can I get the output from the terminal instal of debug console.

Comment: Open the terminal and start the program.

Comment: How can I do it automatically?

Comment: By the way, it work well on windows while not on macOS. 

Comment: What does _"automatically"_ mean? On save, on button click, on change?

Answer (score -2):

Bruh.

Click on the terminal tab in vscode.

Then run the the program.

$ devinjonw> ./main.e

Comment: How can I do it automatically? It works well on windows while not on macOS.

Comment: Well, on windows Ctrl+~. So on mac maybe command + ~? In settings of vscode you can look for hot keys.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me. I mean how to make Visual Studo Code execute the executable main automatically.

Comment: Visual Studo Code does not execute the code. With code runner you likely need to configure the extension to use your compiler to compile the code, then run the program. Code runner is a neat tool but you should consider learning how to use the compiler to compile your code. And how to run the executable. Then you will understand how to configure code runner. In fact you will realize that code runner is not even that good and you would be better of using a make file to compile your code. And then run the executable from the terminal. On windows likely code runner could find the msvc compiler.

Comment: Exactly, I just want to run some simple code.

Comment: Then you must look up how to configure code runner for you environment. No way for anyone to help you since we do not know your exact environment. You need to read the vscode extension documentation on what to do. Likely in vscode you will need to create a folder and file in the workspace ./vscode/settings.json and configure the code runner paths to use your compiler, and use your main.